# Chromium Profile from .deb package to snap version

Tags: chromium, snap

I have just upgraded Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04

I copied my Chromium profile from my 18.04 install (was a .deb package install) - which in my case was everything in ~/.config/chromium

After searching I found that if I copy from from:

~/.config/chromium/Profile 1 to ~/snap/chromium/current/.config/chromium/Profile 1

I would get all my save profile data back into the snap Chromium installation.

On my 20.04 Snap Chromium installation I do not have /.config file.

EDIT: My workaround is install the old deb Chromium from here:
https://fosspost.org/tutorials/chromium-deb-package-ubuntu-20-04

And then I was able to copy my old 18.04 profile.

But it would be great to get my profile/saved bookmarks etc from the old .deb pacakage of Chromium to the new snap version.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man1/chromium-browser.1.html) for chromium, it seems that you can tell it where to look for profiles. You could try to install the snap version again, then execute this command pointing to your existing profile directory:

```
chromium-browser --user-data-dir=/home/user/.config/chromium
```